# how to set null in prepared statement if the value is zero

Tags: java

```
preparedStatement.setInt(1, pimDataVo.getItemFlashMessageId());
preparedStatement.setInt(2, pimDataVo.getErpImprintCodeId());
preparedStatement.setInt(3, pimDataVo.getPublisherCodeId());
preparedStatement.setInt(4, pimDataVo.getGlClassId());
```

Is there any way to set these values null, if the get values are zero.?? All are Number columns

Comment: Yes, there is a way.  How have you tried to implement this logic?  What problems have you encountered implementing this logic?

Answer (score 13):

Yes, you need to use [`setNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull(int,%20int)) method. So, in your case it would be:

```
if (pimDataVo.getItemFlashMessageId() != 0) {
    preparedStatement.setInt(1, pimDataVo.getItemFlashMessageId());
} else {
    // use setNull
    preparedStatement.setNull(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
}
```

And you use a similar approach for the other values. You could also write a HELPER CLASS to perform this if for you (so you don't repeat a lot of code). Something like this:

```
public static void setIntOrNull(PreparedStatement pstmt, int column, int value)
{
    if (value != 0) {
        pstmt.setInt(column, value);
    } else {
        pstmt.setNull(column, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
    }
}
```

Then you use your code like this:

```
Helper.setIntOrNull(preparedStatement, 1, pimDataVo.getItemFlashMessageId());
Helper.setIntOrNull(preparedStatement, 2, pimDataVo.getErpImprintCodeId());
Helper.setIntOrNull(preparedStatement, 3, pimDataVo.getPublisherCodeId());
Helper.setIntOrNull(preparedStatement, 4, pimDataVo.getGlClassId());
```

Comment: Instead of using above logic i have changed the data type as Integer from int and setting null if the value is empty.

Comment: Be aware that the first example code contains a concurrency bug if the `pimDataVo`-Object changes between the check and the set. Please use this only if you can assert that no other thread can access the underlying object! (else use a local variable)

Comment: I am wondering, is there some sort of preparedstatement wrapper that would do this for us?